# Не могу заставить писать бота в лс при входе (дискорд python)

Tags: python, discord, бот

Я уже всё менял и переписывал, Даже брал готовое код нечего не работает. Помогите!

````
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
 
TOKEN = "токен"
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=('!'))
bot.remove_command( 'help' )

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    member_id = member.id
    user = bot.get_user(member_id)
    await user.send('privet')
 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Я запущен!")
 
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Привет всем!",
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
bot.run(TOKEN)```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если вы пробовали запустить скопированный код, и он не работал, то стоит проверь - разрешено ли писать в ЛС данному пользователю.